# Native sharing requires the Facebook for Android application

Tags: facebook

i have installed Facebook Android app,but my code

```
public void shareUsingNativeDialog() {
    if (playerChoice == INVALID_CHOICE || computerChoice == INVALID_CHOICE) {
        ShareContent content = getLinkContent();

        // share the app
        if (shareDialog.canShow(content, ShareDialog.Mode.NATIVE)) {
            shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.NATIVE);
        } else {
            showError(R.string.native_share_error);
        }
    } else {
        ShareContent content = getThrowActionContent();

        if (shareDialog.canShow(content, ShareDialog.Mode.NATIVE)) {
            shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.NATIVE);
        } else {
            showError(R.string.native_share_error);
        }
    }
}
```

it's tip Native sharing requires the Facebook for Android application.
so why??

Answer (score 0):

No need, default mode of ShareDialog will be Mode.AUTOMATIC. It will check if the facebook app is installed.